# Kafka in a box: unable to send messages from host

Tags: python, vagrant, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I created a Vagrant/Ansible playbook to build a single-node Kafka VM.

The idea is to provide some agility when prototyping: if we want a quick & dirty Kafka message queue we can simply `git clone [my 'kafka in a box' repo]`, `cd ..` and `vagrant up`.

Here's what I've done so far:

Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest:9092, host: 9092

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "kafkaPlaybook.yml"
  end

end
```

... and the Ansible `kafkaPlaybook.yml` file:

```
---
- hosts: all
  user: vagrant
  sudo: True

  tasks:

    - name: install linux packages
      action: apt update_cache=yes pkg={{item}} state=installed
      with_items:
        - vim
        - openjdk-7-jdk

    - name: make /usr/local/kafka directory
      shell: "mkdir /usr/local/kafka"

    - name: download kafka (the link is from an apache mirror)
      get_url: url=http://apache.spinellicreations.com/kafka/0.8.1.1/kafka-0.8.1.1-src.tgz dest=/usr/local/kafka/kafka-0.8.1.1-src.tgz mode=0440

    - name: untar file
      shell: "tar -xvf /usr/local/kafka/kafka-0.8.1.1-src.tgz -C /usr/local/kafka"

    - name: build kafka with gradle
      shell: "cd /usr/local/kafka/kafka-0.8.1.1-src && ./gradlew jar"
```

When I `vagrant up` the box gets provisioned. I'm able to `vagrant ssh` and perform the basic producer/consumer tests locally, e.g.

```
cd /usr/local/kafka/kafka-0.8.1.1-src
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties                               #start zookeeper
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties                                      #start kafka
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic tests                #start a producer
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning  #start a consumer
```

When I type messages in the producer window they appear in the consumer window. Great.

I tried connecting to kafka from the host using the kafka-python package:

```
>>> from kafka import KafkaClient, SimpleProducer
>>> kafka = KafkaClient("127.0.0.1:9092", timeout=120)
>>> kafka.ensure_topic_exists('turkey')
No handlers could be found for logger "kafka"
>>> kafka.ensure_topic_exists('turkey')
>>> producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)
>>> producer.send_messages("turkey", "gobble gobble")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/awoolford/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/producer.py", line 261, in send_messages
    return super(SimpleProducer, self).send_messages(topic, partition, *msg)
  File "/Users/awoolford/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/producer.py", line 188, in send_messages
timeout=self.ack_timeout)
  File "/Users/awoolford/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/client.py", line 312, in send_produce_request
    resps = self._send_broker_aware_request(payloads, encoder, decoder)
  File "/Users/awoolford/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/client.py", line 148, in _send_broker_aware_request
    conn = self._get_conn(broker.host, broker.port)
  File "/Users/awoolford/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/client.py", line 55, in _get_conn
    timeout=self.timeout
  File "/Users/awoolford/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 60, in __init__
self.reinit()
  File "/Users/awoolford/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 195, in reinit
self._raise_connection_error()
  File "/Users/awoolford/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 75, in _raise_connection_error
    raise ConnectionError("Kafka @ {0}:{1} went away".format(self.host, self.port))
kafka.common.ConnectionError: Kafka @ precise64:9092 went away
```

The `kafka.ensure_topic_exists` call was made twice. The first time it's run, it returns a warning and then creates the topic, so I can see that Python is talking to Kafka on port 9092. However, I'm unable to send messages to the queue.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The advertised.host.name and advertised.port needed to be set in config/server.properties. I added the following two lines to the playbook:

```
- name: uncomment and set advertised.host.name
  lineinfile: dest=/usr/local/kafka/kafka-0.8.1.1-src/config/server.properties 
              regexp='^#advertised.host.name=<hostname routable by clients>'
              insertafter='^#advertised.host.name=<hostname routable by clients>'
              line='advertised.host.name=localhost'
              state=present

- name: uncomment and set advertised.port line
  lineinfile: dest=/usr/local/kafka/kafka-0.8.1.1-src/config/server.properties 
              regexp='^#advertised.port=<port accessible by clients>'
              insertafter='^#advertised.port=<port accessible by clients>'
              line='advertised.port=9092'
              state=present
```

... and now it's possible to provision a single-node Kafka cluster:

```
git clone https://github.com/alexwoolford/vagrantKafkaBox
cd vagrantKafkaBox
vagrant up
```

If I were to start this again, I would probably have provisioned a lab Kafka using [Wirbelsturm](https://github.com/miguno/wirbelsturm).